# How to deploy a Node.js + webpack bundled web app to production?

Tags: node.js, deployment, web-deployment, production, pm2

I have a web app which has a frontend and a backend. I want to deploy it to a production server. The frontend is bundled with Webpack. All the files go to a single file in the `dist` folder. This folder also has an `index.html` file which is copied from my project. The client will access this file when she uses the web app. I use `babel` command the bundle the server side files to a `lib` sub-folder of the `dist` folder. Now I have everything inside the `dist` folder when I build my project for production.

My project has an express http server and a websocket server. Assume that I deploy my server side code to `pm2`, how to serve users the client side? Do I need to use another web server to host the client side? What will you do?

Comment: this is a very open ended question. there are many routes to go down which is dependent on the scale of your application

Answer (score 0):

One way is, use

> nginx web server

to route to the node application. I am assuming that your server side code is working fine and you are able to serve the static/dynamic content from the backend.